# C++ zlib inflate failing - translation of c# fixup?

Tags: c#, c++, translation, zlib, deflate

I'm trying to inflate a string using zlib's deflate, but it's failing, apparently because it doesn't have the right header. I read elsewhere that the C# solution to this problem is:

```
public static byte[] FlateDecode(byte[] inp, bool strict) {
    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(inp);
    InflaterInputStream zip = new InflaterInputStream(stream);
    MemoryStream outp = new MemoryStream();
    byte[] b = new byte[strict ? 4092 : 1];
    try {
        int n;
        while ((n = zip.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0) {
            outp.Write(b, 0, n);
        }
        zip.Close();
        outp.Close();
        return outp.ToArray();
    }
    catch {
        if (strict)
            return null;
        return outp.ToArray();
    }
}
```

But I know nothing about C#. I can surmise that all it's doing is adding a prefix to the string, but what that prefix is, I have no idea. Would someone be able to phrase this function (or even just the header creation and string concatenation) in C++?

The data which I'm trying to inflate is taken from a PDF using zlib deflation.

Thanks a million,
Wyatt

Comment: you can format your code by selecting it and hitting the '101010' icon. I did it this time.

Comment: Sorry, just an oversight. Teach me to work at four in the morning.

Comment: First, try to actually deflate some random data with zlib. If your code can inflate it back, then the problem is with the data you have. Otherwise, post your C++ code so we can look for possible errors together.

Comment: The code comes straight from the developer - it works fine. The trouble, I believe, is an optional header and possibly footer which the pdf format either adds or elides, but people don't discuss it much in depth.

Answer (score 1):

I've had better luck using [SharpZipLib](http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpZipLib/) for `zlib` interop than with the native .Net Framework classes.  This correctly handles streams from C++ (`zlib` native) and from Java's compression classes without any funny business being needed.

Comment: Thanks for that, and I'll keep it in mind for the future. Unfortunately, I'm not presently using .NET. Do you know of any alternative solution which will work with mingw?

Comment: @wyatt - I see that my answer has missed your point. Why don't you post your C++ code that fails and take it from there?  You can edit the C++ code into the question.  zlib in C++ ought to be a slam dunk, depending on where the stream came from (which information should also be included in the question).

Comment: If you are not using .NET what is the purpose of this question? If your question is C++ code it might help NOT posting C# code and asking a .NET question.

Comment: @Ramhound - I think the problem is with reading a stream using zlib in C++.  Suggestion was that the C# logic in the question might fix the problem, but this ought not to be necessary.  If it is needed, then a C++ version should be not too hard to work out.

Comment: @Steve - I read the question again and the purpose of the question makes sense now.

Comment: The deflated code comes from a pdf, I'll add that to the question in a second. The code I'm using comes straight from the zlib site, at http://www.zlib.net/zpipe.c described at http://www.zlib.net/zlib_how.html

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any prefixes, sorry. Here's what the logic appears to be; sorry this isn't in C++:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(inp);
InflaterInputStream zip = new InflaterInputStream(stream);
```

Create an inflate stream from the data passed

```
MemoryStream outp = new MemoryStream();
```

Create a memory buffer stream for output

```
byte[] b = new byte[strict ? 4092 : 1];
try {
    int n;
    while ((n = zip.Read(b, 0, b.Length)) > 0) {
```

If you're in strict mode, [read up to 4092 bytes](http://sharedcachedocu.indexus.net/html/M_SharedCache_WinServiceCommon_SharpZipLib_Zip_Compression_Streams_InflaterInputStream_Read.htm) - or 1 in non-strict mode - into a byte buffer

```
        outp.Write(b, 0, n);
```

Write all the bytes decoded (may be less than the 4092) to the output memory buffer stream

```
    zip.Close();
    outp.Close();
    return outp.ToArray();
```

Clean up, and return the output memory buffer stream as an array.

I'm a bit confused, though: why not just cut array `b` off at `n` elements and return that rather than go via a `MemoryStream`? The code also ought really to take care to clean up the memory streams and `zip` on exception (e.g. using `using`) since they're all `IDisposable` but I guess that's not really important since they don't correspond to I/O file handles, only memory structures.